# Virtual Method Throw new NotImplementedException();

Tags: c#, inheritance, windows-runtime

I got a class A, an inherited class B, and another class C that inherit from B.

In my class A i just want to define some methods but not implement it, if i declare it as abstract i must implement it in my inherited Class, and i don't want it.
I wanna to implement that methods for example in my C class

Is that procedure correct?

```
 public class A 
{
    public virtual string getValue()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
 ....
 }
```

the second class

```
public class B: A {...}
```

the third class

```
public class C:B {

   public override string getValue()
    {
        ...
        //return a string

    }
```

or i must use interface?

Comment: A side note: When implementing a method which always throws an exception, you should consider adding a summary to it saying: `This method always throws a NotSupportedException`

Comment: What is a point of having `B` ? Do you need base class? Then do not make `A` abstract, but request implementation (by throwing `NotImplementedException` in base class and making them virtual). If you need to hold instances of different `C` classes, then indeed, use interface.

Comment: if A::getValue is virtual, why does it even have a body?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the method as abstract and make B abstract too, so only C would have to implement `getValue`.

You can of course use an interface instead, it depends on what you're actually doing.

If you insist on having an instance of B and not using an interface I would use `NotSupportedException` instead:

```
public virtual string getValue()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: can i create an instance of B?

Comment: @ArghArgh if it's abstract, no.

Comment: as i suppose... but i need to create instances of B and C, for this reason i don't use the abstract method

Comment: @ArghArgh then interface is probably the right answer, because if both A and B don't have the `getValue` method, then it isn't really inherited, it's just a method you want to add.